# Snap a division to another division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have 2 divs which are inside a wrapper div. Wrapper div is draggable. I am using jquery-ui

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="biggerDivision"></div>
    <div class="smallerDivision">>/div>
</div>

<div class="snapDivision"></div>
```

wrapper is draggable because I have to drag both biggerDivision and smallerDivision together but I have to snap only the smallerDivision to snapDivision. biggerDivision and smallerDivision are of different size

JQuery:

```
$('#wrapper').draggable({
    snap: ".snapDivision"
});
```

doing this is snapping wrapper to snapDivision

here is the fiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/buownnbn/

what changes should I make to snap my smallerDivision to snapDivision not the whole wrapper.

Comment: this is work around , try it ..  https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/buownnbn/3/

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any straightforward way to do this.

This is only a work around for your scenario

```js
$('.smallerDivision').draggable({
    snap: ".snapDivision",
    drag : function(event, ui){
        $(".biggerDivision").css("top", ui.position.top + 23); 
        $(".biggerDivision").css("left", ui.position.left - 23); 
    }
});

$('.biggerDivision').draggable({
    handle: ".smallerDivision"
});
```

```css
.biggerDivision {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px
}
.smallerDivision {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    border-top : 23px solid green;
    border-bottom : 50px solid green;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    left:30px
}
.snapDivision {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="biggerDivision"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivision"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="snapDivision"></div>
</body>
```

Known issue : not able to drag using  `.biggerDivision` element

Comment: I have to set the draggable property on wrapper only, thats the constraint, and that makes it more difficult :( can you please suggest modification for that